# VBA, Object variable or with block variable not set” , Using Set gets Object Required

Tags: excel, vba

Getting error `Object variable or with block variable not set`. But when I `set` these variables I am getting `object required`. I tried changing the variables to `Range` I get my original error.

Code:

```
 Dim nameColumn As String
    Dim ScoreColumn As String  

    Sheets("Load check data").Activate
With Rows(1)
    nameColumn = Split(.Find(Sheets("Input").Range("A2"), .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, _
            xlWhole).Address, "$")(1)
    PreviousColumn = Split(.Find(Sheets("Input").Range("B2"), .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, _
    xlWhole).Address, "$")(1)
End With
```

Comment: ```.find``` is probably failing to find anything and that makes ```.address``` invalid on a null object.

Comment: Don't work with the `Address`. Store the result of the `Find` in a `Range` variable, test if it is not nothing, then use the column *number*.... Or if you prefer to work with the `.Address`, you still need to test if the `Find` succeeded.

Comment: thanks guys got it.

Comment: @excelguy if you got it, write an answer!